# Retrieve path of running plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, plugins, file-path

In my plugin's directory I've got some XML settings files that I'd like to parse at a particular point during execution of the plugin. Is there a way to get the absolute path where the plugin's .pyc file is located?

Comment: It is not a problem of QGIS but a problem of Python: [Python - Find Path to File Being Run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296501/python-find-path-to-file-being-run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://spatialgalaxy.net/2013/11/06/getting-paths-with-pyqgis for a discussion of paths in PyQGIS.

Comment: Please include the main points of the post you linked into your answer. This is the only way to avoid the answer going useless in case of "link rot".